# Origen de la locución "en la inopia"

Tags: expresiones, historia, locuciones

Antiguamente, la palabra *inopia* era sinónima de *pobreza*, como así lo atestigua el *Autoridades* (tomo G-M, 1734):

> INOPIA. s.f. Pobreza, ò falta de lo necessario. Es voz puramente Larina *Inopia*.

De hecho, también registra *inope* como "pobre", aunque afirma que entonces tenía poco uso. Ejemplos de este significado se pueden ver en el CORDE en el siguiente texto de 1488:

> A la qual plega saber que en el principado de Cathalunya es vna villa, que se llama Ceruera, la qual, por las conmociones de las guerras passadas y por pestilencias y otros infortunios, queda muy destruhida, en tanto que los creedores que reciben censales y aun mas prestaciones, vista la inopia grande, han hauido pactar con aquella que les paguen, daqui adelante, medias pensiones; la qual concordia es passada, y se obserua por todos los laycos.

Aún se recoge, de hecho, este significado en el DLE, aunque como voz culta:

> **[inopia](https://dle.rae.es/inopia)**
>
> Del lat. *inopia*.
>
> 1. f. cult. Indigencia, pobreza, escasez.

Acto seguido recoge la locución coloquial a la que estamos más acostumbrados:

> **[en la inopia](https://dle.rae.es/inopia)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. En la más absoluta ignorancia de algo.

Esta locución se registra por primera vez en el DLE en 1984, pero no puede ser tan reciente. ¿O sí? Acabo de encontrar este ejemplo de 1973:

> Por cierto que aquella casa había pertenecido a un viejo militar porfiriano que se quedó en la inopia, con deudas por todos lados [...].

¿Cuándo y cómo pasó "vivir en la inopia" de significar "vivir en la pobreza" a "vivir en la ignorancia"? ¿Es realmente tan reciente la expresión? ¿Se usa con el sentido de "en la ignorancia" en todos los países de habla hispana?

> *Sorprendentemente, un acuerdo de este calibre ha pillado en la inopia a Wall Street, como denota que las acciones de Capital Cities-ABC cerraron a la baja en la Bolsa de Nueva York el pasado viernes.*
>
> La Vanguardia, 02/08/1995 (España).

Comment: Interesante, Mi primera conjetura sería que ocurrió ahí una transferencia semántica: *pobreza* de información, de comprensión, que se hace equivaler, se iguala,  a *ignorancia*

Comment: En Colombia cuando decimos "en la inopia" queremos decir "en la absoluta pobreza". El significado de ignorancia es nuevo para mi. Y dado que "inopia" no es una palabra muy común, la gente que la usa generalmente hace la claridad inmediatamente después diciendo algo como "Diego está **en la inopia**, anda **[en la inmunda](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikcionario:Colombianismos)** (pobreza)"

Answer (score 2):

## A lo que preguntas **sobre la antiguedad del uso de inopia con la acepción de *"ignorancia"* —y no de *"pobreza"*, como actualmente consta en el diccionario, desde 1984—, he podido dar con algunos registros anteriores de la fecha que citas**

**En la búsqueda de material hallé dos registros con una anterioridad de ochenta y setenta y dos años (80 y 72) años previos a que la Real Academia Española incorpore el sentido de `total ignorancia de algo`**, que coloquialmente posee la palabra.

Se puede razonar que la traslación (ampliación) semántica ocurrida con la palabra tiene bastantes sentido, desde el sentido original de **escasez** y **carencia** hacia el uso de ***carencia* (o *falta de*) conocimiento** que es la ignorancia.

Tal como lo dicho, el ejemplo más antiguo que encuentro se halla en este libro de poesías ["Rudezas de un cuarentón"](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?id=0000187688&page=89), de Emiliano Balás (impreso en 1904)

> [image: Rudezas de un cuarentón]

donde en la pagina 89 la voz ***inopia*** está connotando ignorancia `(...)Y forma una amalgama repugnante / De Barbarie y cultura, inopia y ciencia, (...)`

> Vuelve horrísono Marte
>   A recorrer del orbe la ancha esfera
>   Produciendo espantosas hecatombes
>   En Europa, en el Asia y en America;
>   Aquí luchas feroces intestinas,
>   Allá terrible, bárbara y sangrienta
>   Comenzó entre dos pueblos antagónicos
>   Despiadada y desigual pelea;
>   Mueve al uno el derecho,
>   Injusticia y el natural instinto de existencia,
>   El honor y prestigios de su raza
>   Que ya en remotos tiempos consiguirea
>   Llegar del adelanto hasta la cumbre
>   Con superioridad enorme, inmensa.
>   Y al romper hoy con anticuados moldes
>   Y en veinte años al tocar la méta
>   Del progreso actual, desentendiéndose
>   De seculares prácticas, añejas,
>   Dió elocuente lección de su cordura,
>   Siendo en la humana historia la primera
>   Nación que ha demostrado clareamente
>   A aquellos que pretendan
>   Adelantar, precisan separarse
>   De Rancias vetustísimas ideas.
>   De otra parte, un coloso
>   Insaciable y voraz como la fiera
>   Que habita entre los témpanos helados
>   Marcha veloz cruzando las estepas
>   Y forma una amalgama repugnante
>   De barbarie y cultura, ***inopia*** y ciencia

---

El segundo escrito (de 1912) está también bastante alejado de la fecha de reconocimiento del uso coloquial actual del término. Es de una obra de autoría de Angel Salcedo y Ruiz, en donde se refiere a la figura de Francisco Acenjo Barbieri (dentro de unas serie de músicos españoles).

> [image: Fransico Acenjo Barbieri]

En la [pagina 196](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=2sIwAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=inopia&f=true) se puede ver el término **inopia** ya usado en el sentido de ignorancia

> [image: texto pagina 196]
>
> ¡Oh, época dichosa la del Renacimiento! Entonces las castañuelas se paseaban triunfantes por ambos mundos, acompañando las armas victoriosas de nuestros soldados y dándo nueva vida a los alegres bailes populares. Entonces la imprenta contribuía a extender los conocimientos históricos-castañéticos, y lo que antes fue triste inopia, se convirtió en alegre exuberancia de noticias. Ya en el siglo XVI, muy graves escritores españoles, como el padre Mariana y otros, se ocupaban seriamente de la zarabanda, la chacona y otros famosos bailes propios de aquellos populares instrumentos. Fray Jerónimo Román en sus Repúblicas, se recreaba haciendo constar que en todos los pueblos de nuestra península se bailaba con castañetas, y que las mujeres moriscas españolas, tenían *donaire en el bailar* (¡cuidado con el fraile!), a lo cual podemos añadir el dicho de Cervantes en su comedia La Gran Sultana:
>   No hay mujer española que no salga
>   del vientre de su madre bailadora.